# using parameter with three values to get different results in query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have select with p_water which has 3 values 0,1,2 and if I choose 1,2 i will get results from tables where field water is 1 or 2 , but if I choose 0 i want to get combine of 1 and 2. How will i do it ?
   AND zs.water = nvl(:p_water,zs.water) this cant help me about 0 value.

Thanks

```
SELECT rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA DATUM_DOKUMENTA,
         rua.VRSTA_promjene VRSTA_promjene,
         COUNT (*) broj_racuna,
         SUM (NVL (rua.duguje, 0)) UKUPNO_BLAGAJNA,
         ,zs.vodovod 
    FROM nve_racuni_uplate rua, nve_potrosaci ptr ,nve_zone_snabdjevanja zs,nve_vodomjerna_mjesta vm
   WHERE     rua.RADNA_GODINA = :P_GODINA   
         AND ((PTR.VODOMJERNO_MJESTO = VM.SIFRA AND  VM.ZBIRNI='N' ) or (PTR.VODOMJERNO_MJESTO = VM.SIFRA_ZBIRNOG))   
         AND zs.vodovod = nvl(:p_vodovod,zs.vodovod)
         AND (   (:p_vrsta IS NULL AND rua.vrsta_promjene IN ('1', '2'))
              OR (:p_vrsta IS NOT NULL AND rua.vrsta_promjene = :p_vrsta))

GROUP BY rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA, rua.VRSTA_promjene,zs.vodovod
ORDER BY rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA, rua.VRSTA_promjene,zs.vodovod
```

`p_vodovod` is parametar with values `0,1 2`

Comment: Post your query. You may need to do something like `AND zs.water = case when nvl(:p_water,zs.water) in (1,2)
                  then <you result>
                  else
                  <al_rows>
                  end;`

Comment: i posted query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if I choose 0 i want to get combine of 1 and 2. How will i do it

Uuse `CASE` statement for evalaution.

Use this:

```
     SELECT rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA DATUM_DOKUMENTA,
         rua.VRSTA_promjene VRSTA_promjene,
         COUNT (*) broj_racuna,
         SUM (NVL (rua.duguje, 0)) UKUPNO_BLAGAJNA,
         zs.vodovod
    FROM nve_racuni_uplate rua,
         nve_potrosaci ptr,
         nve_zone_snabdjevanja zs,
         nve_vodomjerna_mjesta vm
   WHERE     rua.RADNA_GODINA = :P_GODINA
         AND (   (PTR.VODOMJERNO_MJESTO = VM.SIFRA AND VM.ZBIRNI = 'N')
              OR (PTR.VODOMJERNO_MJESTO = VM.SIFRA_ZBIRNOG))
         AND zs.vodovod IN (CASE
                               WHEN (NVL ( :p_vodovod, zs.vodovod)) = 1
                               THEN 1
                               WHEN (NVL ( :p_vodovod, zs.vodovod)) = 2
                               THEN 2
                               ELSE
                                zs.vodovod 
                           END)
         AND (   ( :p_vrsta IS NULL AND rua.vrsta_promjene IN ('1', '2'))
              OR ( :p_vrsta IS NOT NULL AND rua.vrsta_promjene = :p_vrsta))
GROUP BY rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA, rua.VRSTA_promjene, zs.vodovod
ORDER BY rua.DATUM_DOKUMENTA, rua.VRSTA_promjene, zs.vodovod
```

Also note that you should not use old SQL join technique. You must use ANSI sql join.

Comment: missing right parenthesis when nvl (:p_vodovod,zs.vodovod) in (1,2) then (1 == ,2

Comment: @mikrimouse Did you executed what i have posted. I dont see any syntax issue

Comment: inconsistent datatypes expected number got char that is what i get now ( (select  0 ||','||1','

Comment: @mikrimouse .Try now. I fixed it